# Unable to install any add-in for Excel Desktop in MacOS Catalina (Microsoft Excel cannot access the file)

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, office365

I get an error when I try to install an add-in for MacOS Catalina (10.15.4) and Excel for Mac (16.37 20051002)

As a sample, you can try Microsoft People Graph.

[image]

[image]

**Update1:**

I have tried to download the People-Graph.xlsx and open it. As a result, I see

[image]

[image]

Comment: First check would be firewall or something like Little Snitch. 2nd would be to try the url in a browser rather than as a redirect to Excel. If it's a corporate Mac, ask your IT department.

Comment: No firewall, no antivirus. It is a home PC.

Comment: …and my 2nd test? paste the url into a browser...

Comment: What @Tetsujin said. Though that worked for me (Office 2016) With a little investigating I found you can get the Add-in directly from an MS web page. I would download it (manually...) put it on the desktop and add it from that file.

Comment: > …and my 2nd test? 
Please, see my **Update1**

Answer (score 0):

Despite the error, I opened the My Add-ins dialog and after clicking the Refresh button the add-in appeared on the list. Then I was able to add it.

[image]